# g++ warning options for casting pair?

Tags: c++, g++

I just found that C++ doesn't give any warnings for casting from `pair<double, int>` to `pair<int, int>`, which is a little surprising. Here is my program `test_pair.cpp`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    std::vector<pair<int, int> > v;
    pair<double, int> p = make_pair(3.8, 3);
    v.push_back(p);                                                           
}
```

I compile it using `g++ test_type.cpp -Wall -Wconversion`, but still no warnings are generated. I am using g++ v4.6.1. Anyone got any idea how to make g++ generate a warning for this, or it just can't be done?

Comment: What is this notation? I'm unfamiliar with it: `v.push_back({p});`.

Comment: sorry, I was trying to use C++11 features, I should remove the brackets.

Answer (score 4):

Pairs (and tuples) are constructible from almost anything that fits. In particular, each element can be constructed from anything that's implicitly convertible to it. Basically, it "does what you expect". The `pair` has constructor templates that look something like this:

```
template <typename U, typename V>
pair(U && u, V && v) : first(std::forward<U>(u)), second(std::forward<V>(v))
{ }
```

However, you should just say:

```
v.emplace_back(3.8, 3);
```

Comment: +1, but there is a nitpick, they can be constructed from anything that is *implicitly* convertible, not just convertible. That has been the standard wording for a long time (C++03, not sure about C++98), even though with C++03 the restriction could not be implemented.

Comment: v.emplace_back(3.8, 3) still doesn't generate any warnings. But thanks for the explanation. I think this implicit casting feature can be a little confusing.

Comment: The relevant contructor for the example in question is actually `template< class U1, class U2 >pair( const pair<U1,U2>& p );`

Comment: @leftaroundabout but std::pair<int, int> p{3.8, 3}; also compiles without warning. Somehow in this particular case narrowing conversions are allowed.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Yes, an excellent point. Of course I had already included it implicitly, but I've edited the post to make it visible :-)

Comment: @chtlp: `emplace` isn't supposed to generate any warnings, it was just a suggestion how to write the same code more idiomatically. Newer versions of GCC let you enable warnings for narrowing conversions, by the way.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Could you be more specific how to do this? I tried -Wconversion with no luck, by the way.